# Understanding relation between abelian differential and meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

So I'm trying to understand some relation between meromorphic function and abelian differential (i.e. meromorphic differential) over a compact Riemann surface $M$. The basic question is whether the coefficient functions of abelian differential form a meromorphic function.

If $f:M\to\Bbb C_{\infty}$ is a meromorphic function then $f(z)dz$ in local coordinate $z$ on $M$ defines an abelian differential. If $\omega$ is an abelian differential and if I define  $c_1$ to be an abelian differential with $dz$ for each local coordinate $z$, then $\omega/c_1$ is a meromorphic function so the coefficient function of $\omega$ defines a meromorphic function. So I think from the given meromorphic function, I can define an abelian differential whose local coefficient is the given one, and from the given abelian differential, I can get a meromorphic function which is a coefficient of the given one. Does it make sense?

Comment: $dz$ is not globally defined. If $f$ is a non-constant meromorphic function then the meromorphic differentials are the $g df$ for meromorphic functions $g$. In a local coordinate it gives $g(z)f'(z)dz$.

Comment: @reuns Ah, you're saying assiging $f(z)dz$ on each coordinate $z$ is not compatibly defined whereas $df$ is. But I think $c_1$ can be defined. If $z = w(z_1)$ then $w'(z_1)dz_1$. Hmm... right?

Comment: No no $c_1$ is not compatibly defined neither.